# Including Fixture files to be under test with PHPUnit

Tags: composer-php, phpunit, code-coverage

I am developing a Laravel package and some classes are generated by the package via a console command - i.e they do not exist in the package itself but will be created and placed in the users `app/Models` directory, for example. I have created Fixtures for these so I can test the generated classes effectively but I'm unsure how to get them to be picked up in code coverage.

I've tried amending my phpunit.xml to include these as sources:

```xml
<phpunit ...>
...
  <source>
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
      <directory suffix=".php">./tests/Fixtures/app/Models</directory>
    </include>
  </source>
...
</phpunit>
```

But this doesn't seem to do the trick.

At the moment, my composer has the following:

```json
...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Me\\MyPackage\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
      "src/helpers.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/",
      "Tests\\Fixtures\\App\\": "tests/Fixtures/app"
    }
  },
...
```

I've tried moving `"Tests\\Fixtures\\App\\": "tests/Fixtures/app"` to `autoload.psr-4` but no joy. My thinking here was that when running `composer dump-autoload` these would be included in the bootstrapping of Laravel. Also, I'm not sure this is the correct approach as these files are purely for testing and shouldn't be available via the package. (Now thinking that a custom bootstrap file needs to be created to include my regular package classes and my fixtures? I'm unsure if this is the right way and more of a hack however.)

At the moment, my Fixtures are not included in coverage and ideally I want them included.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Composer itself? Usually, Composer does not generate any code coverage

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `coverage/include` element is deprecated from 10.1. My phpunit.xml had

```xml
...
  <coverage pathCoverage="true">
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
    </include>
  </coverage>
...
```

Which just needed changing to:

```xml
...
  <coverage pathCoverage="true">
  </coverage>
...
```

My `sources` element above picked up the fields for coverage but did not include the ones I wanted despite being added in `<source>`. It seems that while deprecated, `<coverage>` was overriding this.